# Returning Latitude, Longitude values from folium map on mouse click to python script (streamlit webapp)

Tags: python, web-applications, onclick, folium, streamlit

I am writing a webapp where the user will click on the map and the latitude, longitude will be returned to the python script. the webapp is written on streamlit and for the map I am using folium. Currently, I used folium.LatLngPopup() to get the on click lat long of the clicked location, but I am very confused how to retrieve the values in my python script for further processing.

This is how it looks currently:

[image: This is how it looks currently]

#code snippet

```
import streamlit as st
from streamlit_folium import folium_static
import folium
m = folium.Map()
m.add_child(folium.LatLngPopup())
folium_static(m)
```

There might not be a native solution to it but any workaround will be appreciated!

Comment: What specific part are you confused about or having trouble with?

Comment: Passing those latitude longitude values from the pop-up to python variable.

Comment: Currently, the package only displays a Folium map, it does not have bi-directional data transfer. If this is functionality you desire, I suggest opening an issue on the GitHub repository (I'm the package developer)

Comment: Hey Randy, I used your package, thanks for having it there in the first place. I'll open an issue on github regarding it. But is there a way to deal with it for now, I tried a many ways but my lack of JS knowledge and folium's limitation on Js->python communication kinda held me implementing it.

Comment: No, there isn't a way to deal with it at this moment. As I said, data only flows one-way currently, from Python to JavaScript. There are no return values.

Answer (score 4):

If you can directly use the value instead of assigning it, you can just use `map['last_clicked']['lat']` and `map['last_clicked']['lng']` where `map` is defined. For example here I just print every location's lat/lng, but instead of just returning them, in a function you can do any operation you need:

```
import folium as fl
from streamlit_folium import st_folium
import streamlit as st

def get_pos(lat,lng):
    return lat,lng

m = fl.Map()

m.add_child(fl.LatLngPopup())

map = st_folium(m, height=350, width=700)


data = get_pos(map['last_clicked']['lat'],map['last_clicked']['lng'])

if data is not None:
    st.write(data)
```

Comment: Please provide working code with continuous lat/lng output, explain how you run this with the `streamlit` server, and how you exit.

Comment: Is it possible to feed the click event-data back into streamlit-folium? I was expecting to be able to e.g. center the map on the location of the mouse click, but I have not had any luck in getting the click data back into the map and have it react like I expected.

Comment: Answered your question not2qubit in new answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I recently encountered the same problem to get the latitude and longitude then print it or save the values to a variable. Apparently, I found out the usual streamlit is static as I tried to create a streamlit.button which is supposed to add 1 to variable counter if clicked. Result: the variable counter is printed as 1, regardless how many I clicked.

To be able to take the input, the streamlit component should be ['bi-directional'](https://docs.streamlit.io/en/latest/develop_streamlit_components.html#create-a-bi-directional-component).
I might not be able to explain it clearly as I am still newb both in python or in javascript, but in short it suppose to listen to the change in the values.

The solution is to create the bi-directional component and later I found this awesome repo [streamlit-light-leaflet](https://github.com/andfanilo/streamlit-light-leaflet). To run it, just follow along the README.md. Assuming you already install streamlit in the virtual env, do the `npm install` and `npm run start`. Then run the '`streamlit run file.py`' in different terminal/command line. Click the url from the terminal where you run the streamlit.

If the map doesn't show, go to `my_component/frontend/src/index.tsx` and put your mapbox.com accessToken. To get the accessToken, you should sign up first to mapbox.com. It would be best practice to use `.env` and call your mapbox accessToken from there, to keep the code cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Building on the answer of francesco morri, I added the missing parts to make it run that address the questions under it. Super grateful about francescos answer.

```py
# my_app.py
import folium as fl
from streamlit_folium import st_folium
import streamlit as st


def get_pos(lat, lng):
    return lat, lng


m = fl.Map()

m.add_child(fl.LatLngPopup())

map = st_folium(m, height=350, width=700)

data = None
if map.get("last_clicked"):
    data = get_pos(map["last_clicked"]["lat"], map["last_clicked"]["lng"])

if data is not None:
    st.write(data) # Writes to the app
    print(data) # Writes to terminal
```

Run it with:

```bash
streamlit run my_app.py
```