# How to create on click popup which includes plots using ipyleaflet, Folium or Geemap?

Tags: python, geospatial, folium, ipyleaflet, geemap

I like getting a popup when I click on the map. The popup includes a plot that I get based on the coordinates of the click. In the code below I used Folium to manually do this:

```
import folium
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt

center = [46.3014, -123.7390]

# Some random data that I like to plot in the popup.
data = pd.DataFrame({'x': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
                     'y': [5, 3, 6, 7, 2]})

chart = alt.Chart(data).mark_bar().encode(
        x='x',
        y='y')
m = folium.Map(location=center, zoom_start=13, tiles="Stamen Terrain")
folium.Marker(
    location=center,
    popup=folium.Popup(max_width=450).add_child(
        folium.VegaLite(chart, width=450, height=250)
    ),
).add_to(m)
m
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Note that the barplot is just an example. All I need is to get the center coordinate when I click the map so that I can use them for generating the actual plot that goes into the popup.

I know Folium has a `ClickForMarker` which returns the coordinate but to my understanding, there is no way to output coordinates to a variable. On the other hand, I cannot show any plot in the `ClickForMarker` as in `folium.Marker`, so this option doesn't help.

I decided to get the coordinates using ipyleaflet. The best I could find is as follow (from [here](https://geemap.org/notebooks/mouse_click_coordinates/)):

```
from ipyleaflet import Map, basemaps, basemap_to_tiles, Marker
from ipywidgets import Label
import ipywidgets as widgets
from ipyleaflet import WidgetControl

m1 = Map(
    layers=(basemap_to_tiles(basemaps.Esri.WorldGrayCanvas), ),
    center=(center),
    zoom=13
)
output_widget = widgets.Output(layout={'border': '1px solid black'})
output_control = WidgetControl(widget=output_widget, position='bottomright')
m1.add_control(output_control)

def handle_interaction(**kwargs):
    latlon = kwargs.get('coordinates')
    if kwargs.get('type') == 'click':
        Map.default_style = {'cursor': 'wait'}

        with output_widget:
            output_widget.clear_output()
            print(latlon)
    Map.default_style = {'cursor': 'pointer'}

m1.on_interaction(handle_interaction)
m1
```

This one returns the coordinates (lower right) but it has two issues: firstly, I don't know how to save the coordinates in a variable that I can use later, and secondly, I cannot move the map since when I click and hold the mouse to move the map, it only returns the coordinates.

**So I just wonder how can I combine ipyleaflet and Folium to get click driven pop up which includes plot? Or is there a better way to do all these?**
Thanks

[image]

Comment: Maybe [Returning Latitude, Longitude values from folium map on mouse click to python script (streamlit webapp)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63413571/returning-latitude-longitude-values-from-folium-map-on-mouse-click-to-python-sc) post will help you.

Comment: Thanks, I tried those before and non of them actually work.

Comment: Please have a look here if that can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74716733/13843906