# Python folium - Circle not working along with popup

Tags: python, leaflet, folium

I found some nice solutions here:

[How to create on click popup which includes plots using ipyleaflet, Folium or Geemap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73339847/how-to-create-on-click-popup-which-includes-plots-using-ipyleaflet-folium-or-ge)

which potentially would allow me to assign more things to the marker when it's clicked. In my situation I have a lot of circles assigned to the marker, but they appear all which doesn't look well.

[image]

I need the `folium.Circle`  populated at the moment when I click on the marker. It could appear along with the pop-up information.

My code looks as follows:

```
fm = folium.Marker(
   location=[lat,lng],
   popup=folium.Popup(max_width=450).add_child(
   folium.Circle(
       [lat,lng],
       radius=10,
       fill=True,
       weight=0.2)),
    icon = folium.Icon(color='darkpurple', icon='glyphicon-briefcase'))
  map.add_child(fm)
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work, as my map comes without some features:

[image]

Despite no error from Python's console side, I have an error in the map console

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'addLayer')
at i.addTo (leaflet.js:5:64072)**

and I have no faintest idea how to solve it

Is there any option of making my circle populated just when clicked on the marker?

**UPDATE:**

With this approach:

```
 mapCirclVar = map.get_name()

 js_f = """
 $(document).ready(function () {
 function onClick(e) {
    var circle = L.circle([e.latlng.lat, e.latlng.lng], {radius: 10, 
 fill: true, weight: 0.2}).addTo({map});
 }
 circle.on('click', function (e) {
 alert("Hello, circle!");
 });
 });
 """.replace("{map}", mapCirclVar)


 ci.add_child(
        folium.Marker(location=[lat,lng],
                  tooltip='<strong>City to survey:</strong> ' + city,
                  popup=js_f,
                  icon = folium.Icon(color='red', icon='glyphicon- calendar'
                                     )
                ))
```

I see some mess in pop-ups instead of what I want to see...

**UPDATE II:**

[Show path in folium map by clicking or hovering marker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74436743/show-path-in-folium-map-by-clicking-or-hovering-marker)

As per an answer in this tread I tried the following ways:

```
from folium.map import Marker, Template

job_range = """
{% macro script(this, kwargs) %}
$(document).ready(function() {
function onClick(e) {
 var circle = L.circle([e.latlng.lat, e.latlng.lng],{
 radius: 10,
 fill: true,
 weight: 0.2}).addTo{{ this._parent.get_name() }};
}
circle.on('click', function (e) {
alert("Hello, circle!");
});
});
{% endmacro %}
"""

  Marker._template = Template(job_range)
```

but it doesn't work either, as console says that the marker cannot be identified. Another example:

```
js_f = """
$(document).ready(function () {
function onClick(e) {
    var circle = L.circle([e.latlng.lat, e.latlng.lng], {radius: 10, 
fill: true, weight: 0.2}).addTo({map});
}
circle.on('click', function (e) {
alert("Hello, circle!");
});
});
""".replace("{map}", mapCirclVar)


e = folium.Element(js_f)
html = map.get_root()
html.script.add_child(e)
```

is still not good.

[image]

**UPDATE III**

By searching the web I've found:

https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/blob/main/folium/vector_layers.py#L318

which make sense, as we can define the class and use the jinja template.

My code, which looks like this:

```
class Circle(Marker):
"""

"""
_template = Template(
"""
{% macro script(this, kwargs) %}
$(document).ready(function() {
function onClick(e) {
 var circle = L.circle([e.latlng.lat, e.latlng.lng],{
 radius: 10,
 fill: true,
 weight: 0.2}).addTo{{ this._parent.get_name() }};
}
circle.on('click', function (e) {
alert("Hello, circle!");
});
});
{% endmacro %}
"""
)

def __init__(
    self,
    location: [lat,lng],
    radius: float = 50,
    popup: Union[Popup, str, None] = None,
    tooltip: Union[Tooltip, str, None] = None,
    **kwargs: TypePathOptions
):
    super().__init__(location, popup=popup, tooltip=tooltip)
    self._name = "circle"
    self.options = path_options(line=False, radius=radius, **kwargs)
    

work_radius = Circle()

 fs.add_child(work_radius)
```

I have the following errors:

**popup: Union[Popup, str, None] = None,
NameError: name 'Union' is not defined**

**ValueError: Marker location must be assigned when added directly to map.**

Comment: I am not that familiar with javascript, but it seems that in the UPDATE II linked answer the ```click_template``` first gets the current configuration of the marker (perhaps including its identification?) and then the extra click is added. With your ```job_range``` the marker template gets a new functionality without the existing infos

Answer (score 0):

*Not necessarily the best approach - but a smooth alternative to @gentleslaughter's implementation:*

You could use a `click_action` argument in `folium.Marker` with a JavaScript function that will add the circle to the map whenever the marker is clicked!

```
js_f= """
    function onClick(e) {
        var circle = L.circle([e.latlng.lat, e.latlng.lng], {radius: 10, fill: true, weight: 0.2}).addTo(map);
    }
"""
```

Here the exact same `folium.Marker` with the `click_action`:

```py
fm = folium.Marker(
    location=[lat, lng],
    popup=folium.Popup(max_width=450),
    icon=folium.Icon(color='darkpurple', icon='glyphicon-briefcase'),
    click_action=js_f,
)
map.add_child(fm)
```

Comment: map_051dd91dffba2723263e44df4edeb606 is not defined this is an error I get. Despite using the .replace("{map}", mapCirclVar) after your script.

Comment: I've sorted the problem mentioned in my earlier comment, but now Console says nothing but seems like the click action doesn't work at all.